# Excel Add-In Query Access Database

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vlookup

I have an Access Database with all of our parts. I'm making an Excel Add-in for users to use. They can query a part by doing the following (in any excel cell):

```
=MUN("VOLTAGE",A3)
```

This function will query the Access Database and find the VOLTAGE value that corresponds to the PARTNO value (in this case the PARTNO value is in Cell "A3" of the user's Excel file).

When I started to create the add-in, I was testing everything solely in Excel (my database was in Excel) and I soon realized that was stupid.

Here's my VBA thats SOLELY IN EXCEL:

```
Function MUN(what, partNo)
Dim ws As Worksheet, aCell As Range, pos As String, tablex As String, LastColumn As Integer, LastRow As Long, LastCell As Range, LastC As String, LastR As Integer

p = "P:\Engineering\Programs"
f = "partsDB.xls"
s = "Sheet1"
path = "'" & p & "[" & f & "]" & s & "'!"
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("table")

    'DETERMINES THE LAST COLUMN AND ROW USED IN THE WORKSHEET (THIS WILL HELP DETERMINE THE TABLE FOR VLOOKUP)
    LastRow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastColumn = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    LastC = Replace(Cells(1, LastColumn).Address(False, False), "1", "")
    LastR = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

    'DETERMINES THE COLUMN POSITION OF THE "WHAT"
    Set aCell = ws.Rows(1).Find(what:=UCase(what), LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    pos = aCell.Column

    'SETS THE TABLE
    tablex = "A$1:" & LastC & "$" & LastR

    MUN = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(partNo, Range(tablex), pos, False)
End Function
```

I came across another issue. I need to do a VLOOKUP with multiple arguments. I need to do a VLOOKUP where XX = "XXX" and YY = "YYY" then return "ZZZ".

Since MS Access can use SQL queries, how do I connect to an Access database and do a query that will replicate what's in the function above, and also do a VLOOKUP with multiple arguments?

Comment: Slight problem with this plan.  Access is a client database, not a server database.  Excel is also client software.  Therefore, even if you wrote wonderful code, there will probably be connection problems.

Comment: I noticed people can access external Excel Files without even opening them, how would this be different?

Answer (score 0):

in VBA do something like this:

```
dim accdb as object
set accdb = CreateObject("Access.Application")
accdb.Open "your access database path"
```

note: your access db will need to be somewhere where everyone can access it

then I'm thinking (I've no experience doing this from excel - I use excel from access) - that you'll need to instantiate like a db object to use the current database, and to execute an sql statement using that db object to retrieve back the data you want.

Sorry this isnt a very complete answer, but it might be enough for you to get started.